# How to exit a while loop nested in a for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I guess this should be simple. The first part of the code is to initialize the variables. My problem is with the while loop. If the condition `j == len(time)` is achieved, I need to exit the WHILE loop and the FOR loop. But the thing is that once the condition is true, the while loop iterates once again; therefore, time is out of index.

```
import numpy as np

# Variables to initialize the problem
timeframe = 25
dt=0.025
dat=[(0, 5)]
dat.append((timeframe,dat[len(dat)-1][-1]))
time = np.arange(dat[0][0],dat[-1][0]+dt,dt)   
dat_discretized = np.zeros(len(time)) 

#While inside a for loop
j=0
for i in range(len(dat)):
    while   dat[i][0] <= time[j] <= dat[i+1][0]:
       dat_discretized[j] = dat[i][1] 
       j += 1
       print(j)
       if j == len(time):
           break
```

How can I exist the while loop without rechecking the while condition?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't even need these two loops, it can be accomplished with numpy indexing. Can you describe what you're trying to do?

Comment: Once you fix this, you'll find `dat[i+1][0]` also errors out, since you might be calling `dat[len(data)]`. You need to define the border case by either doing `for i in range(len(dat)-1):` or defining the last case explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(dat)):
    breakFor=false
    while   dat[i][0] <= time[j] <= dat[i+1][0]:
       dat_discretized[j] = dat[i][1] 
       j += 1
       print(j)
       if j == len(time):
           breakFor=true
           break
    if breakFor:
        break
```

Comment: The booleas False/True should be in capital letters